# How to measure response time for each and every request in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I want to run Azure Durable Functions and measure the response time taken from the time the trigger is pulled to the time it returns.

The sequence of events I want to measure is as follows

1. Send HTTP request to Durable Functions (start measurement)
2. Orchestration functions and activity functions send data to each other and execute the process.
3. Results are returned and the process ends (measurement ends)

[image]

The reason why I want to do this is to investigate how the response time of Durable Functions is affected when the size of data transferred by the orchestration function and the activity function is different.

How can I measure the time between the trigger being pulled and the response being received in Azure Portal or Applications Insights?

The environment I am using is,
Azure Free Tier
Python programming model v2

Comment: Can you please add a sample code you are using?

Comment: Why do you need the code?

Is the code relevant to get it from the Azure Portal or Applications Insights?

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere that you need this from Portal or application Insight, So I thought you want to do it using code

Comment: Sorry, I will correct that it is the way you see it from the Azure Portal or Applications Insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed the below code to Azure Function App.

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging
import  numpy  as  np
import  pickle  

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  

### client function ###
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)
runtime  =  status.runtime_status
output  =  status.output
return  f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
result  =  yield  context.call_activity("activity1", "")
return  result

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  activity1(blank: str) -> str:
data  =  np.random.rand(1024  *  1024  *  5)
serialized_data  =  pickle.dumps(data)
serialized_size  =  len(serialized_data)
return  str(serialized_size)
```

Post deployment, I am able to see the functions in function app.

[image]

Then, I invoked the Http Trigger function.

[image]

There are multiple ways you can check the total time taken by Http function to complete the execution.

1. ***Check in Monitor blade as shown below.***

[image]

2. ***You can check the total response time in Application Insight as well.***

[image]

[image]

You can also graphically visualize the execution in vs code using ***Durable Function Monitor*** extension.

Install the ***Durable Function Monitor*** extension in vs code and then connect to your function app. You can refer to this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor) to know more about the mentioned extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting three different methods.
Am I correct in understanding that the first and second methods measure the response time of the sequence of events from the time the trigger is pulled to the end of the process, rather than the average response time over a period of time or the fragmented execution time?

Comment: Yes, it captures the total time taken by the http function to complete

Comment: The way we are checking the time for Http function in `Monitor` blade, in the same way you can also validate the completion time of Orchestrator function and activity function which will have completed before Http function